# Creating a bat file

Tags: file, batch-file, automation, hex, edit

I want to automate hex editing,
Hex editor is HxD.exe
I will copy HxD.exe to the same folder with the exe that will be edited.
I want some sort of:
open hxd.exe open etc.exe
change 0004A0-0004A3 **00 00 80 3F**
to
00 00 40 3F

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the details of HxD.exe, it's hard to say exactly. You could use Windows PowerShell to achieve the surrounding operations, however. For example:

```
# Assuming hxd.exe and <SourceFile> exist in c:\MyFolder
Set-Location -Path:c:\MyFolder;
# 
Start-Process -FilePath:hxd.exe -ArgumentList:'-hxd args -go here';
```

Instead of changing the current directory context, you can also set the working directory of the process like this:

```
Start-Process -WorkingDirectory:c:\MyFolder -FilePath:hxd.exe -ArgumentList:'-hxd args -go here';
```

Depending on how hxd.exe works, you might also be able to place hxd.exe in an arbitrary folder, and pass in your source file using its absolute path:

```
$SourceFile = 'c:\MyFolder\sourcefile.bin';
$HxD = 'c:\path\to\hxd.exe';
Start-Process -FilePath $HxD -ArgumentList ('-SourceFile "{0}" -Range 0004A0-0004A3' -f $SourceFile);
```

Hope this gives you a push in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any command line options listed on the HxD website, so I'm going to give you a pure PowerShell alternative, assuming that editing the file is more important to you than the program that you use to make the edits (and that you have PowerShell available)...

Copy the following into a file called Edit-Hex.ps1:

```
<#
.Parameter FileName
The name of the file to open for editing.

.Parameter EditPosition
The position in the file to start writing to.

.Parameter NewBytes
The array of new bytes to write, starting at $EditPosition
#>
param(
    $FileName,
    $EditPosition,
    [Byte[]]$NewBytes
)
$FileName = (Resolve-Path $FileName).Path
if([System.IO.File]::Exists($FileName)) {
    $File = $null
    try {
        $File = [System.IO.File]::Open($FileName, [System.IO.FileMode]::Open)
        $File.Position = $EditPosition
        $File.Write($NewBytes, 0, $NewBytes.Length)
    } finally {
        if($File -ne $null) {
            try {
                $File.Close()
                $File = $null
            } catch {}
        }
    }
} else {
    Write-Error "$Filename does not exist"
}
```

Then your example would work like this:

```
.\Edit-Hex.ps1 -FileName c:\temp\etc.exe -EditPosition 0x4a0 -NewBytes 00,00,0x40,0x3f
```

Note that the new values must be entered as a comma separated list to make an array, and that by default the values will be interpreted as decimal, so you need to either convert to decimal or use the `0x00` format to input hex.

If this doesn't work for you, it would be helpful for you to provide the command line options for HxD so that we can help you build an appropriate wrapper.